# Change control buttons to understandable english

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have this `[D] [D+] [B] [B&D] [F]` within a class named `control`, several times on a single page

That's all well and dandy, but, each of those buttons are links which activate JavaScript,  so I can't change them as easily as I'd hoped too.

How can I change every instance of those control buttons on a page to specific text, while retaining their function?

such as `[D] to [Foo] and [D+] to [Bar]` ?

http://jsfiddle.net/N57FX/

This probably won't do you any good, as I'm quite literally saying exactly what I was saying before. I just want to change every instance of [D] in the control class on the page (multiple posts per page) to [Foo]

Comment: actual code would be helpful

Comment: If you have coded in such a way that the label decides the functionality of a button, it is a very bad design. Please share your code or give more details.

Comment: @tracevipin is correct. My answer doesn't even make that much sense. Please provide a test case (preferrably on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) and I'll revise my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If these are `input` elements, it's as easy as:

```
$(".control[value=D]").val("Foo");
```

If they are anchors or any other element, it becomes a little trickier:

```
$(".control").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === "D";
}).text("D");
```

Comment: It might work, but it doesn't make much sense to do something like that unless you don't have control over the HTML markup. Is that the case?

Comment: I do not have such control, if I did, I wouldn't be asking how to change it via jQuery or Javascript :P

Comment: You did miss to mention that in your question though. It's kind of crucial information ;)

Comment: sorry, I kinda just assume that if I'm using javascript or jquery it implies that I can't change it server side.

But you are right, I'll specify next time.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have titles in your fiddle, use those :

```
window.addEventListener ('load', function () {
  [].slice.call (document.querySelectorAll ('.controls a')).forEach (
      function (b) { b.innerHTML = b.title; });
});
```

See forked fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/URPa4/

If you want different text in the title and the button, then add an attribute `data-text` to each control with the desired text and use

```
window.addEventListener ('load', function () {
  [].slice.call (document.querySelectorAll ('.controls [data-text]')).forEach (
      function (b) { b.innerHTML = b.getAttribute ('data-text'); });
});
```